How can one tell from the outside if a Java plum is sweet or just astringent?
Some Java plums (aka syzygium cumini, Malabar plums, Jambolan plums or black plums) are very astringent and some slightly sweet. How can one tell from the outside if a Java plum is sweet or just astringent?
